# UrlConnection.getInputStream() returns an exception that is null in Java

Tags: java, inputstream

I have the following java code

```
try {
    String u = "http://webapi.com/demo.zip";
    URL url = new URL(u);
    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d('downloaderror', e.getMessage());
}
```

But for some reason, the `InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream()` causes an error and the catch block is fired.  And when the catch block is fired, the value of `e` is `null`.

Does anyone konw what is wrong with my `ucon.getInputStream()` ?  I know for a fact that `http://webapi.com/demo.zip` exists, because I'm able to download the file from my web browser.

*EDIT*
Here's the stack trace on ucon.getInputstream()

```
java.lang.Exception
            at com.example.instantramenz.samplewebview.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:94)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The value of `e` is `null` or the String printed contains the text `null` (ie. the message is `null`)?

Comment: the value of e is null.  And then null.getMessage() causes the app to crash after

Comment: Please post the stack trace. If I remember correctly, exceptions in a catch-block can never be `null`.

Comment: I get a 404 and text/html. Can you use Apache HttpClient?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the actual url is somethign that can only be accessed internally on my own network.  But I can confirm that the file actually exists.

Comment: If you use Java 7+, use a try-with-resources statement!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - the question you marked at duplicate doesn't seem to discuss the issue I'm having with getInputStream().  Can you refer me to a question that deals with this specific error and possible solutions?  Thanks

Comment: What issue are you having with `getInputStream`? I thought the issue was with a `null` catch parameter (which should not be possible).

Comment: I'm expecting the getInputStream() to execute normally so that it can carry on to the next lines of code (which I haven't displayed in this question).  I'm just trying to figure out what's wrong with the way i'm using getInputStream(). Thanks

Comment: If you're getting `null` as a value for the exception parameter, you've got bigger problems. I'll re-open but try @ElliottFrisch's suggestion and use a different http client, where you can easily inspect the status code and response body.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I just posted the stack trace

Comment: 1. There is no such method as `InputStream.getInputStream()`. 2. Exceptions are thrown, not returned. 3. Thrown exceptions are never null, but their messages can be. 4. You should log the exception itself, not just its message.

Comment: @EJP thhansk for point 1, i corrected the title.  In any case, i was able to resolve the issue by temporarily using android.os.StrictMode in some places, and extending the ASync task in other places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed the problem by putting this line of code before downloading the file:

```
            android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            android.os.StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```